# Unexpected behaviour with base plot.sf vs ggplot for sf objects

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, r-sp

#### Background

I'm experiencing some unusual behaviour in plotting an `sf` class object using R's base plotting methods for `sf` objects, and the behaviour is further unusual when compared with the output from `ggplot2`.

Plots are meant to show an overlay of a `POLYGON` feature collection on top of a `POINT` feature collection. They have consistent CRS settings and the bounding box extent of the polygon feature fully envelops the bounding box of the point collection.

#### Reproducible example:

```
library(sf)
library(geohashTools)
data(meuse, package = "sp")
meuse_sf = st_as_sf(meuse, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 28992, agr = "constant")
meuse_sf <- st_transform(meuse_sf, crs = st_crs(4326))

meuse_gh <- geohashTools::gh_covering(meuse_sf)
```

The `gh_covering` function from `geohashTools` should create a grid that fully envelops the extent of all points in `meuse_sf`.

This is the plot from base plots. Note that it looks like some points are outside of this grid.

```
plot(meuse_sf[1])
plot(meuse_gh[2], add = TRUE)
```

[image]

At first, this appeared to be a bug in `gh_covering`, but when reproduced in `ggplot2`, it's clear that it is working as intended

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = meuse_sf, aes(colour = cadmium)) +
  geom_sf(data = meuse_gh, fill = NA)
```

[image]

#### Checks

Additional checks for bounding box extents and CRS equivalence came back fine.

```
> st_bbox(meuse_sf)
    xmin     ymin     xmax     ymax 
 5.72319 50.95661  5.76304 50.99156 
> st_bbox(meuse_gh)
     xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
 5.712891 50.954590  5.767822 50.998535
```

And

```
> st_crs(meuse_gh)==st_crs(meuse_sf)
[1] TRUE
```

#### Question

So, what is causing the issue in base plots behaviour here?

#### Session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.3.0      sf_0.9-3           geohashTools_0.3.0 sp_1.4-1
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first plot command, you need to use

```
plot(meuse_sf[1], reset = FALSE)
```

when you want to add elements later.

Comment: Thanks @Edzer. That addresses why overplotting wasn't showing up sometimes. But I'm still not sure about the position error, in why in my question the geohash object wasn't properly overlayed on the points object. I found a way to replicate this error more reliably in a clean session environment by calling in succession. 
`plot(meuse_sf[1])` then `plot(meuse_gh[2])` then `plot(meuse_sf[1])` and then `plot(meuse_gh[2], add = TRUE)`. This produces an overplot like in the image above. I'm guessing this is something graphics device related?

Comment: How about asking the authors of the geohashTools package?